# how display data of database in listview on android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to display data of a database in a listView but my project has a problem.
Where in my code is the problem?
Here is my code:

```
public class Activity2 extends ListActivity {
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {          
                    DisplayContact(c);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
        }

    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
    {

        ListView lstView = getListView();
        //lstView.setChoiceMode(0); //CHOICE_MODE_NONE
        //lstView.setChoiceMode(1); //CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
        lstView.setChoiceMode(2);   //CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
        lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       // presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents_array);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DBAdapter>(this,
                android.R.layout.activity_list_item));
    }
    }
```

**

And here is my database:

```
public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, price text not null);";

    private final Context context;    

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a contact into the database---
    public long insertContact(String name, String price) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular contact---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the contacts---
    public Cursor getAllContacts() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_PRICE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular contact---
    public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a contact---
    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String price) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Compilation error? Exception/crash?

Comment: where in the question is the logcat?

Comment: the listview isnt show data.this is my problem

Comment: Maybe, because you don't fill the ListView adapter? In your onCreate you fill a cursor. Then reset the ListView adapter so many times... I guess you end up with only 1 row shown.

Comment: You should do the cursor fill in DisplayContact, then loop throug the rows to fill the ArrayList, and assign the latter to the ListView. Try to move the setListAdapter AFTER the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and store the values retrieved from database in that array.

```
String str[] = new String[cur.getCount()];
for(int i=0;i<str.length;str++){
      //Assign str[i] the value retrived from cursor
}
```

Then create a list adapter and call listview.setAdapter

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.subcategory_list,
            str);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {

           DisplayContact(c);

        }
        db.close();
    }

public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
{

    ListView lstView = getListView();
    //lstView.setChoiceMode(0); //CHOICE_MODE_NONE
    //lstView.setChoiceMode(1); //CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
    lstView.setChoiceMode(2);   //CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
    lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   // presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents_array);

    MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(c);
   lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and Coustom adapter class as follows.

```
 class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Cursor mCurosr;
    MyAdapter (Cursor c) {
        mCursor=c;
    }



    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        TextView title, detail;
        //set data to ur view
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        //now get ur data from cursor for each row using mCursor using cursor methods.

        return (row);
    }
}
```